# Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet

Tags: windows, сеть, wifi, маршрутизация, openvpn

Замучался уже я. Пните в нужном направлении. Итак, есть OpenVPN сервер на убунте, к нему цепляются три клиента - два Windows и один Андроид. Ключи у всех трех клиентов различные. Конфиги клиентов идентичные. Два клиента работают как часы, а с одним (виндовым) постоянные траблы. Они появляются в виде строки

> Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000

после этого туннель ложится. Обычно эта строка появлялась когда ноут засыпал и терял подключение к WiFi сети. Проблема решалась перезагрузкой всего ноута (переподключение, перезагрузка OpenVPN клиента эффекта не давала). Сейчас эти строки появляются сразу же после установки соединения.

Теперь конкретика:

Конфиг сервера

```js
port 3000
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key  
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh2048.pem

topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

keepalive 10 120
tls-server
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0 
tls-timeout 120
auth sha1
cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
log         /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4
mute 10

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Конфиг клиента

```js
client
dev tun
proto udp
redirect-gateway def1

remote 35.XXX.XXX.72 3000

resolv-retry infinite
nobind

persist-key
persist-tun

mute-replay-warnings

ca ca.crt
cert anton.crt
key client.key

remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC

comp-lzo
verb 4
mute 10

tls-client
auth SHA1

status openvpn-status.log
log openvpn.log
```

Лог клиента

```js
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031 Current Parameter Settings:
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   config = 'client.ovpn'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   mode = 0
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   show_digests = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   show_engines = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   genkey = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031   connect_retry_max = 0
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031 NOTE: --mute triggered...
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031 281 variation(s) on previous 10 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031 OpenVPN 2.4.2 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on May 11 2017
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=77031 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=92662 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=92662 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=498898 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=608274 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=608274 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=717652 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=733279 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:18 2017 us=733279 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 LZO compression initializing
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1622 D:1184 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1622 D:1450 EF:122 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1558,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=467645 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=483279 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498599199,WAIT,,,,,,
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=686398 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498599199,AUTH,,,,,,
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=702031 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000, sid=8208d47f e3397048
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=920776 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=UA, ST=Kh, L=Kharkiv, O=Anton, OU=MyOrganizationalUnit, CN=Anton CA, name=VPN, emailAddress=anton.tramp@gmail.com
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=920776 VERIFY KU OK
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=920776 Validating certificate extended key usage
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=920776 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=920776 VERIFY EKU OK
Wed Jun 28 00:33:19 2017 us=920776 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=UA, ST=Kh, L=Kharkiv, O=Anton, OU=MyOrganizationalUnit, CN=anton-vpn-server, name=VPN, emailAddress=anton.tramp@gmail.com
Wed Jun 28 00:33:20 2017 us=436401 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Wed Jun 28 00:33:20 2017 us=436401 [anton-vpn-server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=702025 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498599201,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=702025 SENT CONTROL [anton-vpn-server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.3 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1625
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1553 D:1450 EF:53 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=905155 interactive service msg_channel=0
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=920782 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 I=9 HWADDR=74:2f:68:ec:c7:19
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=967666 open_tun
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 2] opened: \\.\Global\{FF62B73E-7D2A-4FAF-A38E-170927330DE4}.tap
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 TAP-Windows MTU=1500
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 10.8.0.0/10.8.0.3/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.3/255.255.255.0 on interface {FF62B73E-7D2A-4FAF-A38E-170927330DE4} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.254, lease-time: 31536000]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 DHCP option string: 06080808 08080808 0404
Wed Jun 28 00:33:21 2017 us=983295 Successful ARP Flush on interface [13] {FF62B73E-7D2A-4FAF-A38E-170927330DE4}
Wed Jun 28 00:33:22 2017 us=14532 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Wed Jun 28 00:33:22 2017 us=14532 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498599202,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.3,,,,
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=192720 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=192720 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 35.XX.XXX.72 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=208364 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=25 and dwForwardType=4
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=208364 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=208364 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=223975 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=223975 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=223975 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=239598 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=239598 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=239598 Initialization Sequence Completed
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=239598 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1498599207,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.3,35.XX.XXX.72,3000,,
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=255221 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=255221 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000
Wed Jun 28 00:33:27 2017 us=255221 Recursive routing detected, drop tun packet to [AF_INET]35.XX.XXX.72:3000
```

Таблица маршрутизации клиента до поднятия туннеля

```js
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 13...00 ff ff 62 b7 3e ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 11...56 2f 68 ec c7 19 ......Виртуальный адаптер размещенной сети (Майкрософт)
 10...16 2f 68 ec c7 19 ......Виртуальный адаптер Wi-Fi Direct (Майкрософт)
  9...74 2f 68 ec c7 19 ......Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
  3...54 04 a6 2b 3a 2d ......Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.102     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
    192.168.0.102  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
 Метрика   Сетевой адрес            Шлюз
  6    306 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  6    306 2001::/32                On-link
  6    306 2001:0:9d38:6abd:2c50:1cc8:3f57:ff99/128
                                    On-link
  6    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    306 fe80::2c50:1cc8:3f57:ff99/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

Таблица маршрутизации клиента после установки соединения

```js
===========================================================================
Список интерфейсов
 13...00 ff ff 62 b7 3e ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 11...56 2f 68 ec c7 19 ......Виртуальный адаптер размещенной сети (Майкрософт)
 10...16 2f 68 ec c7 19 ......Виртуальный адаптер Wi-Fi Direct (Майкрософт)
  9...74 2f 68 ec c7 19 ......Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
  3...54 04 a6 2b 3a 2d ......Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP
  6...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Адаптер Microsoft ISATAP #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
Сетевой адрес           Маска сети      Адрес шлюза       Интерфейс  Метрика
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.102     25
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.3     20
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
         10.8.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
     35.XX.XXX.72  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.102     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.3     20
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
    192.168.0.102  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.102    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.3    276
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует

IPv6 таблица маршрута
===========================================================================
Активные маршруты:
 Метрика   Сетевой адрес            Шлюз
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 13    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    276 fe80::4d03:3341:75d7:ba6f/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Постоянные маршруты:
  Отсутствует
```

С сервера пинги на этого клиента не идут. Клиент пингануть сервер по адресу 10.8.0.1 также не может. При пинговании сервера на сервере tcpdump пустой. На клиенте WireShark показывает что пакет ушел. Ответа нет. При попыке зацепится за сервер телнетом WireShark показывает ушедший TCP пакет, а потом цепочку ARP запросов `Who is 10.8.0.1?`

**UPDATE** Немного локализовал проблему. Проблема вознникает только когда клиент подключается к интернету по WiFi. При подключении по кабелю все работает. Было предположение, что это из-за метрик адаптеров (кабель - 20, WiFi - 25, Туннель - 20). Увеличил метрику туннеля до 30 - ничего не поменялось. Кабель работает, WiFi - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день,

Я нашел ваш вопрос через Google, так как у меня такая же проблема.

Домашний роутер с LEDE 17.01, OpenVPN 2.4.2, другой клиент с iOS 10.3.2 работает, VPN маршрутизирует весь трафик, я вижу свой SAMBA сервер. Проблема возникла с лаптопом под Windows 7 SP1, client OpenVPN 2.4.3, и проблема такая как у вас, тоже использую WiFi. Я могу подключиться к серверу по ping, nslookup не работает, но я нашел "workaround" - https://www.snbforums.com/threads/beta-asuswrt-merlin-380-66-beta-is-now-available.38718/page-7#post-320981

В конфигурацию клиента ovpn я записал `pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway local def1"`, так как у моего сервера такая строчка. Всё начало работать, но веб-трафик не идет через VPN, зато я вижу свой SAMBA сервер. Может быть это поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне нужно именно веб-трафик завернуть на VPN